# Summernote dialog not display properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my Summernote that the dialogs/modals are not fit it in exactly . Here's the pic.

[image]

And here my summernote code.

```
$('#summernote_new_post').summernote({
    dialogsInBody: true,
    height: 400,
    minHeight: null,
    maxHeight: null,
    focus: false,
    callbacks: {
        onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
            for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                sendFile(files[i], this);
            }
        },
    },

    dialogsFade: true,
    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['style']],
        ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['fontname', ['fontname']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
        ['height', ['height']],
        ['table', ['table']],
        ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr', 'video']],
        ['view', ['codeview']],
        ['help', ['help']]


    ],
    popover: {
        image: [
            ['imagesize', ['imageSize100', 'imageSize50', 'imageSize25']],
            ['float', ['floatLeft', 'floatRight', 'floatNone']],
            ['custom', ['imageAttributes', 'imageShape']],
            ['remove', ['removeMedia']]
        ],
        link: [
            ['link', ['linkDialogShow', 'unlink']]
        ],
        air: [
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'paragraph']],
            ['table', ['table']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'picture']]
        ]
    },
});
```

Can anyone help me with this? I think there is conflicts with my code. Thank you.

Comment: Anyone can you help me about this? Thanks